# Macro to remove a particular value(s) in cells A2 through A1000

Tags: macros, xls

Help!!!

Need a macro that will delete rows based on the value that is found in Cells A2:A1000. The value with either be East, West or Central.

I have used numerous codes that I have found on this and other websites and keep getting either a value not found(run time error 13) or when it seems like its running, it will stay running for 20 minutes with no visible change.  This needs to delete the rows fast or its just not worth automating it.

I have a spreadsheet that 3 different planners use to sort there orders.  I already have a macro that does the custom sort and paste values for them.  However, they are still manually deleting the rows that pertain to the regions that isn't their's.

I also need it to remove the remaining blank rows up to A1000.  There are numerous vlookup and hlookup formulas in these rows that are currently being deleted manually.

I can provide a copy of the spreadsheet if needed.

Comment: It's always good to see what you have tried. You get community support much quicker then.

Comment: This worked for me http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/815-excel-remove-rows-based-on-cell-value.html#vba